# Store a dictionary of key/value pairs in R in a matrix or a vector

Tags: r, dictionary

How do I store a a dictionary of key/value pairs in R in a matrix or a vector.
I already have a key/value pair of word/ frequency returned from the function termFreq() from the tm package. I want to know how to store this entire dictionary as an element of another matrix

Comment: you can use a list http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list or a named vector http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/named-vector-members but maybe you should have a look in an R tutorial in general

Comment: @Linus - Thanks for your reply. Sorry I was not too clear in my question, I already have a key/value pair of word/ frequency returned from  the function termFreq() from the tm package. I want to know how to store this entire dictionary as an element of another matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the nicest solution would be to store them in a list of lists. Here is an example:

```
library(tm)
doc_ma <- matrix(c('hello once', 'hello twice','goodbye once', 'goodbye twice','welcome once','welcome twice'),2)
```

Example data:

```
     [,1]          [,2]            [,3]           
[1,] "hello once"  "goodbye once"  "welcome once" 
[2,] "hello twice" "goodbye twice" "welcome twice"
```

Create a list of lists with term frequency vectors:

```
my_list <- lapply(1:nrow(doc_ma), function(x) {vector("list", ncol(doc_ma))})   
for(i in 1:nrow(doc_ma))
{
  for(j in 1:ncol(doc_ma))
  {
    my_list[[i]][[j]] = termFreq(doc_ma[i,j])
  }
}
```

Now we can call the term frequency vector of `doc_ma[i,j]` as `my_list[[i]][[j]]`, example:

```
my_list[[1]][[2]]
```

Output:

```
goodbye    once 
      1       1 
attr(,"class")
[1] "term_frequency" "integer"
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian. That was helpful.

Comment: Great, could you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your issue? Thanks!